# Add node at end or beginning of linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to create a server/client program with named pipes in Linux.
Every time a client connects and authenticates, the server stores his data (pid and password) in a linked list.

The problem is that after I store the first client's data, whenever I try to store more data (clients), the program "gives" **segmentation fault**.

```
typedef struct client client, *pno;
struct client
{
    pid_t pid;
    char password[TAM_MAX];
    pno next;   
};

int verify_struct(pno cliente_t)
{
    if (cliente_t == NULL) //verifica se a lista está vazia
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

    pno AddClient(pno cliente_t, pid_t pid, char password[TAM_MAX]) 
    {
        pno new, aux;
        new = malloc(sizeof(client)); //aloca espaço

        if(new == NULL) //verifica se alocou o espaço com sucesso
            {
                printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
                return cliente_t;
            }

        new->pid = pid;
        strncpy(new->password, password, TAM_MAX-1);

        if(verify_struct(cliente_t))
            {
                printf("Should be at start\n");
                cliente_t = new;
                printf("Added at start!\n");
            }
        else
            {
                //insert at end
                printf("Adding in the end!\n");
                aux = cliente_t;
                while(aux->next != NULL)
                    aux = aux->next;
                aux->next = new;
                printf("Added sucssefully!\n");
            }
        return cliente_t;
    }

bool isValidUser(pno cliente,  pid_t pid, char password[TAM_MAX])
{
    while(cliente != NULL)
        {
            if(cliente->pid == pid && strncmp(password, cliente->password, 100) == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            cliente = cliente -> proximo;
        }
        return false;
}

    //progam itself :

int main(void)
{
    pno client=NULL;

    /* --code-- */

    while(1)
        {
                if(request.loggedIn == 0)
                    {
                        client=AddClient(client, request.pid, request.password);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        if(!isValidUser(cliente, perg.pid_cliente, perg.password))
                            abort();
                        //process commands
                    }
        }

}
```

**Outputs:**

```
1st Client -> Should be at start!
           -> Added at start!

2nd Client -> Adding in the end!
           -> segmentation fault (core dumped).
```

Comment: Great!  Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Im using gcc -o server server.c. How can i make it to see debug errors/warnings ?

Comment: You need to run your program in a debugger.  If you are working at the command-line only, then I'd suggest looking into GDB.  It's hard work at first, but it's a skill you absolutely need to acquire!

Comment: i am guessing you have `cliente_t` as `NULL` or garbage which is causing the crash.

Comment: @Bill, if the client is connect and search the linked list to check if it is a valid user and i think the pointer leaves the list in a null "state", maybe its that. Ill update the code with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line to AddClient

```
new->next = NULL;
```

Otherwise `new->next` contains uninitialized memory. Later when you check `aux->next != NULL` (aux is now equal to what new was before), the test does not evaluate to true, because the uninitialized memory does not happen to equal 0. Then you attempt to find another node pointed to by the value in uninitialized memory. It likely contains data which is not actually a legal memory address, hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you ! I really didnt remembered about that memory issue =)

Answer (score 0):

There are two very similar issues:

1. When adding to the end of the list you need to make sure `new->next` contains `NULL`, as @morningstar as already mentioned.
2. When adding to the start of the list you need to make sure `new->next` contains `cliente_t` (prior to assigning it to `new`). For example:

   ```
   printf("Should be at start\n");
   new->next = cliente_t;
   cliente_t = new;
   printf("Added at start!\n");
   ```

The code doesn't compile due to this `cliente = cliente -> proximo;` undefined member... I presume you meant to modify that to `-> next`. Please make sure you test your testcases in the future.

Comment: When i past the code here, i intend to translate it to english-like variables and i missed that `cliente = cliente -> proximo;` . But in my actual code it is correct, the issue was that i was missing `new->next=NULL`